# What does "it" before "even" refer to?

Tags: grammar

In [Runaway Jury (2003)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_Jury), a jury member Nick Easter caught using liquor in jury pool:

> Judge: You still trying to get off my jury, is that it?
>
> Nick Easter: Your Honor, I took an oath to do my best, and I meant it.
>
> Judge: Difficult as that is to believe...**it**'s even more difficult
> to believe this is your liquor.

What does "it" before "even" refer to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a "dummy pronoun", grammatically required but not really meaningful.

If it refers to anything it refers to "that this is your liquor" But you shouldn't really analyse this pronoun as having a reference. Instead treat this as an idiom:

> It's difficult to believe [something]

These dummy pronouns are sometimes called "weather pronouns" from idioms like

> It's raining".

The word "it" in that example doesn't seem to have any reference, but is grammatically necessary.

Comment: James K,  How can you so sure that "it" not referring to "oath" in previous line?

Comment: Two reasons.  Firstly there is an idiom "It's difficult to believe that...."  Secondly the sentence "The oath is difficult to believe that this is your liquor"  doesn't make sense.

Comment: Or more generally the idiom is "It's difficult".  You can say "It's difficult to play trumpet" which means "Playing trumpet is difficult".  The same idiom can be used for "it's easy".